# Reinstalling Ubuntu. Stucked at Grub and bootable USB is not booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I accidentally deleted everything in usr/bin (and possibly more) and trying to recover my Ubuntu.

First, I tried to chroot with a bootable USB but my USB was not recognized by Grub. I have just bought my ASUS zenbook and only had 2 files in my Ubuntu, so I decided to reinstall it.

So, I deleted the Ubuntu partition and inserted my bootable USB. Now, I see a new black page saying GNU Grub with minimal bash in white and cannot access Windows.

I checked my bootable USB on another machine, and it is perfectly working there. What should I do to reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you checked your BIOS and see if your *USB Device* is listed above *Internal Hard Disk* in `boot order`?

Comment: Why do you need to delete Ubuntu partition just install on top of it! In any case chack the boot order

Comment: @George Because I read so. How to check my boot order if I only see Grub?

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht Thanks for your comment. How to get to Bios from Grub?

Comment: reboot your system and use either `esc` or `f10` to get there. Then `advanced --> boot order` to set it to usb

Comment: @George I have been pressing all those but I did not know that I need to press them before it gets to Grub. Now, I was able to change boot order. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to press esc before Grub shows up to change boot orders!